# Why does R interpret '-' and '+' signs as '2' and '3' respectively?

Tags: r, matrix

I have 2 matrices, i am assigning a subset of columns from 1 matrix to the other. One column consists of + and - signs:

```
> ncRNAtable[,3]
[1] - - - - - + + - - - + + + + + + + + + + + + - - - - - - - - + + + +
```

when i assign this to a column in my second matrix, the - signs become 2 and the + signs become 3:

```
> finalmatrix[,5] = ncRNAtable[,3]
```

and then:

```
finalmatrix[,5]
[1] "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "3" "3" "2" "2" "2" "3" "3" "3" "3" "3" "3" "3" "3"
```

I can get around this other ways, but im really interested why this happens? any ideas?

Comment: Can you check the class of the column.  If it is a `factor`, it could get coerced to integer storage value

Comment: because they are `factors` , maybe?

Comment: class(ncRNAtable[,3]) = factor and class(finalmatrix[,5]) = charecter. i guess convert the factor clumn to string?

Comment: Use `finalmatrix[,5] = as.character(ncRNAtable[,3])`

Comment: a matrix by definition is made of only numbers, try doing class(ncRNAtable[,3), if it's class factor, build the finalmatrix as a dataframe and it should be ok